# Search category in products with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have products in ElasticSearch index.
Each product has one or more categories which is stored in field "categories":

```
"categories": [
        {
          "category_id": 1686,
          "name": "Nuts"
        },
        {
          "category_id": 1725,
          "names": "Sweets"
        },
        {
          "category_id": 1239,
          "name": "Chocolate"
        }
      ]
```

I want to full text search product by that categories. For example if I search word "sweets" I want to know exactly which category matches, I need to know its category_id. 
Is it possible by ElasticSearch?

Comment: Yes, but your `categories` field needs to be of type [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

Comment: Yes, You can use `parent` `child` relationship for your problem. [parent_child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html)